# How do I log to different files with Monolog in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, monolog

I want to log messages to separate files depending on the context. Currently everything is going into the environment's log file. How can this be accomplished with Monolog in Symfony2?

Answer (score 0):

In your config files (`config.yml` or `config_dev.yml` and `config_prod.yml`) under `monolog:` register new handlers for each file you want to log to.

```
handlers:
    main:
        type:         fingers_crossed
        action_level: error
        handler:      nested
    nested:
        type:  stream
        path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
        level: debug
```

the environment's log file will receive everything from `debug` level up, but the main logger service will only log with action level `error` and up.

Add your own handlers for the files you want to log to in your config files.

```
cron_logger:
    type: stream
    path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/cron.log"
    level: notice
    channels: "cronchan"
```

You can choose which level of messages will be logged in the file. You should specify which channel will log to this handler. In this case the channel name chosen was "cronchan". At the same level as handlers, register your new channel (you need MonologBundle 2.4 for this).

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        ...
        cron_logger: ...
    channels: ["cronchan"]
```

You can now log specifically to the `cron.log` file by getting the correct channel's service in a controller: `$logger = $this->get('monolog.logger.cronchan');`

Now everything from `notice` level and up will be logged in the `cron.log` file. The messages will possibly also be logged in the environment's log file, but you can [remove the channel from the file's handler's channels](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/channels_handlers.html#switching-a-channel-to-a-different-handler).